# Is there any way to get System.Security.Cryptography work on Windows Phone 8 to generate random numbers?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, cryptography, portable-class-library, rngcryptoserviceprovider

Is there any way to get the classes `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` or `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` work on a Portable Class Library targeting Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store App?

The main reason for that is that I'm trying to get a "true" random value and the `Random` class is useless for my purposes.

I've heard about the PclContrib that "emulates" the `System.Security.Cryptography` for PCL project on Codeplex but I think it doesn't have the functionality I need.

Comment: You can only go for the usual workaround where you define an interface PCL and then supply two separate implementations.